# MYSQL get user rank by performance

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert at MySQL which is proven obvious today but I need help ordering users by sales.

I have two tables. One called users

```
+------------------------+
+ id | fname | lname     +
+------------------------+
+  1 | bob   | french    +
+  2 | fred  | smith     +
+  3 | ted   | nugent    +
+  4 | kyle  | frank     +
+------------------------+
```

and another for sales

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
+ id | date        | commission  | lister      | seller      +
+------------------------------------------------------------+
+  1 | 2017-11-01  | 2200        | 2           | 2           +
+  2 | 2018-01-15  | 1800        | 1           | 1           +
+  3 | 2017-11-07  | 3600        | 2           | 1           +
+  4 | 2017-11-30  | 1252        | 4           | 1           +
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Commission is split 50/50 by the lister and seller.
the lister and seller columns correspond to the user id

I need to find 2 things.

**A) a persons (eg. Bob French) RANK for SUM of his commissions, for sales THIS MONTH**

So Bob should have 50% of sale #3, and 50% of sale #4.

sale #2 isn't in this month

so the half of sale #3 (1800) and half of sale #3 (626) is 2426

The ranks for this month SHOULD be

1. Fred @ 4000 total commission
2. Bob  @ 2426 total commission
3. Kyle @ 626  total commission
4. Ted  @ 0    total commission

I need to return RANK (which is 2 in this case) and TOTAL COMMISSION (which is 2426 in this case) for USER (bob in this case) in this month (november in this case)

**B) I need show the entire above table in a different statement (for supervisors to see everyone ranked. users only see their ranking anonymously.**

It may be the same SQL query for both and then I just pluck the user by id from the result set unless there is a more efficient way.

**What I've tried**

```
SELECT x.id, x.fname, x.lname, y.commission,
FIND_IN_SET( commission , ( 
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( commission ORDER BY commission DESC )
    FROM sales
) ) AS rank

FROM users x
JOIN sales y ON x.id IN (lister, seller)
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

This is working BUT it doesn't limit it to the month. I have tried adding

```
WHERE (date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
```

but it seems to have no effect, as I tried limiting the dates to 2010, and results came back regardless.

Also the above query is returning the RANK by whoever got the SINGLE HIGHEST commission, not the sum of their commissions.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` :

```
select x.id, x.name, sum(commision) as commision from 
(select a.date as date, b.id as id, b.fname as name, a.commision/2 as commision
from sales a join users b
on a.lister = b.id
union all
select a.date as date, b.id as id, b.fname as name, a.commision/2 as commision
from sales a join users b
on a.seller = b.id) as x
where x.date between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-30'
group by x.id, x.name
```

Here the fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ae69a/7

For your filter `WHERE` and ordering, you can add :

```
select x.id, x.name, sum(commision) as commision from 
(select a.date as date, b.id as id, b.fname as name, a.commision/2 as commision
from sales a join users b
on a.lister = b.id
union all
select a.date as date, b.id as id, b.fname as name, a.commision/2 as commision
from sales a join users b
on a.seller = b.id) as x
where (x.date between DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND NOW() )
group by x.id, x.name
order by commision
```

**- EDIT -**

Adding rank : (fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ae69a/30)

```
SET @rank = 0;

SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank,
       y.id,
       y.name,
       y.commision
FROM   (SELECT x.id,
               x.name,
               Sum(commision) AS commision
        FROM   (SELECT a.date          AS date,
                       b.id            AS id,
                       b.fname         AS name,
                       a.commision / 2 AS commision
                FROM   sales a
                       JOIN users b
                         ON a.lister = b.id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT a.date          AS date,
                       b.id            AS id,
                       b.fname         AS name,
                       a.commision / 2 AS commision
                FROM   sales a
                       JOIN users b
                         ON a.seller = b.id) AS x
        WHERE  ( x.date BETWEEN Date_format(Now(), '%Y-%m-01') AND Now() )
        GROUP  BY x.id,
                  x.name
        ORDER  BY x.commision) AS y
```

Comment: You are my new hero. +100000

Comment: I just noticed one thing missing that I need, it all works beautiful but how do I add a column `Rank` into the result set? (ie. what row position is each row)

Comment: @Wazimshizm : Hi there, I prefer make rank outside sql actually, but here we go. Answer updated. Cheers ;) Here the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ae69a/30

Answer (score 0):

select @a:=@a+1 as rank,'@',u.fname ,COALESCE(sum(commission),0)commission,'total commission' from (SELECT sub.dates,(commission*2)commission,sub.lister as id
FROM (SELECT s.dates,(s.commission/4)as commission,s.lister,(select @a:=0)rank
FROM sales s  where s.dates 
between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31')sub
union all 
SELECT sub.dates,(commission*2)seller,sub.seller FROM 
(SELECT s.dates,(s.commission/4)as commission,s.sellerFROM sales s  where s.dates 
between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31')sub)main 
right join users u on u.id = main.id 
group by main.id order by sum(commission)desc